# Obtener empresa por usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel

tengo una duda, actualmente poseo un registro de usuarios el cual esta asociado a una empresa, cuando registro un usuario selecciono a cual empresa pertenece, hasta aqui todo bien, he creado una tabla aparte que se llama empresa_users el cual tiene el id de empresa y de usuario, y otra con la empresa y otra con el usuario, el temas es, como puedo mostrar una vez logueado solo los datos de la empresa a la que pertenece este usuario?, actualmente tengo:

```
$empresas = Empresa::all();

$parents = Empresa::orderBy('nombre', 'ASC')->pluck('nombre', 'empresa_id');

return view('empresa.index', compact('empresas', 'parents'));
```

lo cual desde ya me muestra todas las empresas...
alguna idea?

Con esto ya obtengo por ejemplo el id del usuario actual:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: Cuales vendrian siendo lo usuarios, ¿Los parents ?

Comment: Si, usando el make auth de Laravel.

Comment: la relación es de 1 usuario a muchas empresas o como funciona?

Comment: Coloca tu relacion de la BD para entenderla mejor

Comment: Es 1 empresa a 1 usuario de momento, lo resolvi creo de esta forma obtengo el id de empresa y despues hago un getbyid $getUserByEmpresa=EmpresasUsers::where('user_id',$userId)->get(); hice un modelo EmpresasUsers con id de usuario y empresa...de ahi saco la relacion actual. creo que lo resolvi.